# How to change programmatically DataSet SqlCommand CommandText

Tags: dataset, sqlcommand

I have a generated DataSet with bunch of tables. In one table I have a custom query that I use to select people that are older than 15 years. I would like to change this query during working program, so that the query will look like 'select * from people where age > 17'. Now it looks like 'select * from people where age > 15'.

All that I know is what is the name of this query in DataSet. It's GetNotYoungPeople. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably part of a [SQLDataAdaptor.SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx)

The DataSet is populated by the [SQLDataAdaptor.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill.aspx) method and has no attached queries itself